# Delete unix shared memory segments using a C++ program

Tags: c++, unix, shared-memory, inter-process-communicat, ipcs

I am trying to write a C++ program to delete the shared memory segments. I know it can be done from cmd prompt using

`ipcs -m | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs ipcrm -m`

But I am trying to do it using C++ so that I create a shared memory garbage collector.

The idea is to delete shared memory segments that are not attached to any process( nattach ==0) or the status == NULL

Comment: Have you tried executing the command from C++?

Comment: I think you will have to gain kernel mode privileges if you want to do it by-hand. You may still use existing ABI or API if available, which may be easier :)

Comment: i want to parse the out put of this code and check if nattach==0 and then pass the args to ipcrm  `ipcs -m | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Geoffroy , what API do i use for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally have the the answer to my own question. It can be done using shmctl flags. 
`shmctl(0,SHM_INFO,&shm_info);` gives number of segments currently present.

`shmctl(i , SHM_STAT , &shm_segment)` gives the segment id

it can also be accessed by `shm_segment.shm_id`

```
#include <sys/shm.h>     

int delete_segment(int seg_id){
    if ((shmctl(seg_id,IPC_RMID,0))==-1){
    std::cout<<" ERROR(C++)with shmctl(IPC_RMID): "<<strerror(errno)<<std::endl;
    return -1;
    }else//on success
        return 0;
}

void clean_segments(){

    struct shmid_ds shm_info;
    struct shmid_ds shm_segment;
    int max_id = shmctl(0,SHM_INFO,&shm_info);
    if (max_id>=0){
        for (int i=0;i<=max_id;++i) {
                int shm_id = shmctl(i , SHM_STAT , &shm_segment);
                if (shm_id<=0)
                    continue;
                else if (shm_segment.shm_nattch==0){
                    delete_segment(shm_id);
                }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to a [source code](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.17/util-linux-ng-2.17.2.tar.bz2) of the `ipcrm`, it calls [`shmctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmctl).

```
shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL)
```

Comment: Yes, I know `shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, NULL)` but it only works if you have the segment ids. I need to be able to get a list of all current segment ids an check if there are any processes that are attached to it and check if they are active and delete the non active once's

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest executing `strace ipcrm -m <your-arguments>` and see what system calls it performs. In *most cases* that should be suficient (at least it will point you in the right direction), if not - look at the source code of **ipcrm**. I'm pretty sure you do not need any special privileges (ipcrm on my system does not have SUID or SGID bits set).

Answer (score 0):

The code below use I:

```
    void clean_segments(int startId, int endId) {
    for (int i=startId; i<=endId; ++i) {
        struct shmid_ds shm_segment;
        int shm_id = shmctl(i, SHM_STAT, &shm_segment);
        delete_segment(shm_id);
        printf("Segment %d has been deleted\n", shm_id);
    }}
```

clean_segments(1146894, 6357160);// example of using the code above